# Writing an image in python without using libraries

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to read a bmp image without using python image processing libraries and write the image data into a file.

Here is my code:

```
f = open('test7.bmp', 'rb')
data = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('Image_details.txt', 'wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

But I'm getting the image data like this:

BMÞ       6   (               ¨                     ÿ  ÿ  ÿÿÿÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿ  ÿ   ÿÿÿ    ÿ   ÿÿ  ÿ  ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  ÿ  ÿ     ÿÿÿ   ÿ  ÿ  ÿ   ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ    ÿ      ÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ     ÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿ

Could you help me out in getting the image data in any other format (hex/binary/decimal)?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using python 2.x

Comment: Do you want to see the binary representation of that image file ?

Comment: @BcK : yes...either binary or hex.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just "copy" the image, the only thing you're doing wrong is saving the file as a `.txt` extension - your system probably tries to open that as a text file, and thus you're text editor is showing you binary data like this. If you change the extension to `.bmp`, then it will open like a normal image.

If what you want, however, is to dump a text hexadecimal representation of the image into a text file, you can use the `binascii` module (part of the standard library):

```
import binascii

with open('img.bmp', 'rb') as fd:
    data = fd.read()

with open('img_data.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(binascii.hexlify(data))
```

This will give you a single-line text file, with the hex representation inside it, e.g.:

```
424d7ab80b0000000000...
```

If you want a neatly formatted hex representation (e.g. whitespace every 2 chars, and newline every 10th pair), you can do:

```
import binascii

with open('img.bmp', 'rb') as fd:
    data = fd.read()

with open('img_data.txt', 'w') as fd:
    hex_str = binascii.hexlify(data)
    chunk_size = 10
    hex_list = [hex_str[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex_str), 2)]
    hex_chunks = [hex_list[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(hex_list), chunk_size)]
    data = '\n'.join([' '.join(chunk) for chunk in hex_chunks])
    fd.write(data)
```

Which will yield you a nicely formatted (easier to read, but bigger in size) text representation:

```
42 4d 7a b8 0b 00 00 00 00 00
7a 00 00 00 6c 00 00 00 80 02
00 00 90 01 00 00 01 00 18...
```

Comment: Worth noting is that my second solution - the one with "pretty" printing can also be simplified by using `itertools.islice` and `iter`.

Comment: Is it storing as simple string of hexadecimal representation or is it actually hexadecimal values of the data?
I mean can I do any math operations on the data?